# How to create a wpf template with nested datatemplate (datatemplate in datatemplate)

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I'm totaly new to wpf. I try to create a nested `datatemplate` [like this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSUf1.png) (`datatemplate` inside another `datatemplate`). I managed to create a datatemplate and to connect to `"Object A"` in an `ObservableCollection`, which worked really well. Now I need to have a nested `ObservableCollection` in each `Object A` to display `Object B` and `Object C` in columns. But I don't really know how to do that and can't find examples.

Maybe anyone could give me a hint?

Thanks and regards,
Marlene

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a `ListView` or `ListBox` to display a collection of `Object A` (lets call it `ObjectACollection`), and that `Object A` has properties named (in this example) `ObjectBCollection` and `ObjectCCollection` you could do something like this:

```
<UserControl xmlns:namespaceA="clr-namespace:MyProj.Models.ObjectANamespace"
             xmlns:namespaceB="clr-namespace:MyProj.Models.ObjectBNamespace"
             xmlns:namespaceC="clr-namespace:MyProj.Models.ObjectCNamespace" >
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectACollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="namespaceA:ObjectA">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectBCollection}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="namespaceB:ObjectB">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectBProperty}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectCCollection}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="namespaceC:ObjectC">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ObjectCProperty}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</UserControl>
```